# reverse osmosis (RO) unit shutting off too soon

Tags: plumbing

It has only been about a month since the filters were changed in the RO unit and after completely draining the tank trying to fill a large container I noticed that after full recharging the pressure was lower than before.  I checked full pressure and found that it was only about 1/2 the water pressure of the system (as measured with a pressure gauge) instead of the 2/3 that it is supposed to be when it shuts off filling the tank.

I tried increasing the pressure a bit when full but it still shuts off at around 1/2 the system pressure.  Then I tried decreasing and I got it to shut off a little higher, so I kept decreasing but it eventually went back down without ever reaching close to 2/3.  The literature says to pressurize it to 5-7psi empty, but none of my gauges will read that low, they don't register until at least 10psi.  In the interim of waiting for a new gauge to arrive is there some other way to get the pressure right?  Or is there something else I should try?

Comment: Make and model?  Some RO systems are simple water pressure only, some have pumps etc.   sounds like you have the more complicated system with pumps?

Comment: @Tyson I don't think it has a pump. The tank says PA-E RO-132